# Regex To check that string in last paragraph

Tags: php, regex

I have a text like

```
Hello this is test 
Text:12563

Test This is also Test.This is test
```

Now here Text:12563 not in last paragraph but if i have a text like

```
Hello this is test     

Test This is also Test.
Text:12563
This is test
```

Here the Text:12563 is in last paragrapgh of given text. Now i have to check this with preg_match_all function. Have you any idea about this regular expression.

Comment: why u have java and c tags if you want a preg_match_all solution

Comment: This solution takes more than just a preg_match_all

Comment: can you provide more details regarding this

Comment: your working with a dynamic needle?

Answer (score 1):

Check where there are 2 subsequent linebreaks (new chapter) and after the last time you encounter 2 subsequent linebreaks check for multiline text containing your text before the file ends.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer without using regexp.

```
$text = <<<EOF
Hello this is test     

Test This is also Test.
Text:12563
This is test
EOF;

$paras = explode("\n\n", $text);

$last = $paras[(count($paras) - 1)];

$needle = "Text:12563";

if (strpos($last, $needle)) {
    echo "Found";
}
```